# Put text over image in <td>

Tags: css, html, html-table

I am working on a promotional site where I have advertisements aligned in a table with two rows and as many columns as user would want.

By assigning `min-width: 200px` to the `<td>` element I achieved that my table will increase its width if I add more `<td>` elements. Table is then put inside a `<div class="index">` which gives ability to scroll my table left and right using a scrollbar. In order to test this I added a lot of `<td>` elements in the table.

So Now I want my cells to include text (center aligned x and y) and an image (different across cells) which takes all cell space and lowers an opacity on hover - so that the text below can be seen.

I have to position my `table.index td` - otherwise image overflows my rounded cell corners. I was trying to put my text in some sort of a container and put it below image... Any advice on how to achieve this?

Google chrome example is [here](http://ziga-lausegger.com/strani/index.php).

---

**CSS:**

```
table.index{
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: white;
}
table.index td {
    height: 200px;        /*image height is calculated from this*/
    width: 200px;         /*image width is calculated from this*/
    min-width: 200px;     /*forces table to spread it's width*/
    position: relative;   /*in order for overflow in next line to work*/
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #1A1A1A;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.90);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px #000000;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
table.index td img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
table.index td:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #000000;
}
table.index td img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px) opacity(50%);
}
div.index {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="index">
<table class="index">
<tr>
    <td>
        <img src="../slike/index/2015-12-06-comptech.png"/>
        Obiskal sem sejem Comptech in si ogledal 3D očala Oculus rift.
    </td>
    <td>
        <img src="../slike/index/2015-11-26-objava-avtomatika.png"/>
        Moj članek iz mednarodne konference Utrip prihodnosti je bil objavljen v reviji Avtomatika 138/2015.
    </td> 
    <td> 
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td> 
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
    <td>
        ...
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: So you just want to center the text inside the cell (vertically and horizontally), or you want it to stretch across the cell as well? Are you implying different font sizes for cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
table.index td {
  ...

  vertical-align: middle; /* changed from top */

  text-align: center; /* added */

}
table.index td img {

  ...
  height: auto; /* changed from 100% */
  /* add: */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I suppose this is what you want? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tLetsj19/2/

Comment: Thank you. So why didn't my `height: 100%;` work and `height: auto;` did? One more question. How would I add `padding: 5px` inside a cell, but ONLY for text and not for image?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tLetsj19/2/ why not, just add the padding? Remember to subtract 2 x`padding size` from the `width`/`height` to give the final cell the same `width`/`height` as before. Your `height: 100%;` was giving me some problem on Chrome only, where images are shrink-ed. Idk why but changing to auto surely fixed it.

Comment: But wont this aply padding allso to the image?

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can see in the demo I linked don't you? The images are `position: absolute` so they don't get pushed by the cell's padding.

Comment: OK this worked indeed. But I found out now, that I have to put text in front of image and on hover I want text to increase opacity (to appear) while at the same time I want my image to keep the same animation I have. How could I fix that? Should I put my text into a container or not? I,d perfer not, but if it is necesary it wont be a big deal.

Comment: OK I found the solution. TY.